# Create a collapsible card using HTML, CSS and JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, display

I'm trying to create a collapsible card. I have a `div` object which contains HTML elements

```css
.element {
  background-color: grey;
  margin-bottom: 0.7rem;
  padding: 1.4rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  <div class="content">
    <h2>title</h2>
    <p class="longText">
      different lines of text....
    </p>
    <p>author</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

While the title and author consist of just one line of text, the text inside the elements could be, in principle, of multiple lines.

**What I would like to obtain is a card which contains only the first line of the text inside `<p></p>`, and when I click on it, it expands and reveal the rest of the text. Obviously, if the text is short and 1 line is enough to display it all, then the click should do nothing.**
[image: a card with a long text and one with a short text]
The first card should look like the second, and when clicked expanded to show the full text.

I tried to solve this by setting a `max-height` property in the `css`, and then change it in the `js` script when clicked on the card, but in this way it always show the full text and the script only adjust the height of the cards.
An idea I had was to split the `<p></p>` in two element, something like

```html
<p class="first_line">
...
</p>
<p class="remaining_text" style="display: none;">
...
</p>
```

and then change the display property of `remaining_text` in the `js` script, but that doesn't seems right if I have a lot of card to display in this way.

Comment: Please update to clarify "only the first line of the text" screen size dictates what MAY be considered "first line" on a paragraph.  From your code do you mean that to be only the paragraph with the `class="first_line"` ?  Also you have " different text fields" but there are  no "fields" here only HTML elements.

Comment: `max-height` will only change the `height` of an element when the `height` value exceeds the `max-height`, in which case the `height` will stop a the `max-height` value. You still need to set the `height` property to make your element expand and collapse.

Comment: There is a very clear example of how to do this on w3schools: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transition1 take a look and tell us if this answers your question

Comment: What you need to do is structure your HTML so that the card title is separate from the card body, which is what will expand and collapse. It's all about your HTML structure here.

Comment: @ControlAltDel That example is not about how to create an expandable/collapsible card layout, per se. The OP should be looking more toward accordion layout here. But also, did you know that W3Schools is widely considered to be a poor tutorial site as it often will have outdated, incomplete, or flat out incorrect information? Instead, the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/) is an authoritative resource.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss yes sorry, I'm new to web development, HTML elements are more appropriate terms, I will update the question. By first line I mean a substring of the whole text which occupies a single line of text in an element. I will upload pics

Comment: Sounds like the need for a [<details>: The Details disclosure element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details).

Answer (score 0):

A succinct way to achieve this is to use the proposed [`line-clamp`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/line-clamp/) property. It’s not yet a standard but all the major browsers have implemented it.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.card').forEach(c => {
  c.addEventListener('click', evt => {
    c.querySelector('.longText').classList.toggle('expanded')
  })
})
```

```css
.card {
  background-color: grey;
  margin-bottom: 0.7rem;
  padding: 1px 1rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.longText {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 1; /* number of lines to show */
  line-clamp: 1; 
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
.longText.expanded {
  display: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <h2>title1</h2>
  <p class="longText">Pellentesque consequat odio ex, et vulputate tellus varius eget. Vestibulum arcu risus, semper quis erat in, ornare maximus nisi. Vivamus lobortis tortor lectus, eget suscipit ante cursus et. Donec commodo arcu vitae nibh pretium finibus. Nunc porttitor pretium vehicula. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nulla luctus tempor lectus mollis posuere. Aliquam sodales magna a facilisis cursus. Vivamus sollicitudin vel neque vel aliquam. Mauris eu elementum libero, pretium egestas sem. Morbi sed laoreet tortor, sed tincidunt enim. Donec scelerisque dolor et arcu lacinia congue. Ut bibendum efficitur scelerisque.</p>
  <p>author1</p>
</div>

<div class="card">
  <h2>title2</h2>
  <p class="longText">Maecenas a bibendum eros. Maecenas risus eros, porta eu dui vel, pretium cursus velit. Nulla elementum, sem in sollicitudin feugiat, magna sem blandit ante, eget facilisis orci enim in metus. Proin in felis sed ante iaculis maximus. Nullam tempus, dui non viverra ullamcorper, ligula diam finibus mauris, sed rutrum est ligula vitae sapien. Praesent mattis risus nec justo pretium, at ultricies ipsum commodo. Phasellus condimentum suscipit nisl sed blandit. Pellentesque sed eros et turpis aliquet mattis.</p>
  <p>author2</p>
</div>
```